# Verifying independent tensors implies independent matrices/coordinate representation

Tags: linear-algebra

My course is using Helene Shapiro's book for a second course in Linear Algebra. Chapter 4 is Jordan canonical form. Since she doesn't really talk about tensors (she just defines them in a coordinate sense), I can't see why certain claims are holding.

Luckily my class has went over tensors quite a bit so I have a decent foundation. Here it goes.

Let yi's and zj's be linear independent vectors. More precisely, let them be eigenvectors of two different linear transformations, where no two eigenvectors have the same eigenvalue, i.e. if j≠i, yj and yi have different eigenvalues and are thus independent.

Let (x) denote the tensor product (apologies, I don't know how the syntax works on this site.) It's clear to me that yi(x)zj are linearly independent tensors. However, Shapiro literally *defines* the tensor of two vectors, y(x)z, say of lengths n and m, to be this weird n x m matrix, constructed by scaling y by the coordinates of z, i.e. [(z1)y ... (zn)y] is the matrix, by which I assume she means more-or-less the coordinate representation of the tensor w.r.t. a basis, written simply as an array instead of a list.

What I'm trying to understand is why independence of the set {y1(x)z1,...,yk(x)zr} of tensors implies independence of the set of matrices {[(z11)y1 ... (z1n)y1],...,[(zr1)yk ... (zrn)yk]}.

Much appreciated.